# Unity Metal: Compute shader has 1024 threads in a thread group which is more than the supported max of 512 in this device

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, metal, build-error

I'm compiling a code for unity ios build and keep getting the following error

Metal: Compute shader has 1024 threads in a thread group which is more than the supported max of 512 in this device

pls help me in resolving this error.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means your shader trying to use more threads than iOS supported.

To solve it just reduce using threads in the compute shader by changing this line in your compute shader

```
[numthreads(32,32,1)]
```

to

```
[numthreads(8,8,1)]
```

and also in your c# script

```
_shader.Dispatch(CSMain, 32, 32, 1); to _shader.Dispatch(CSMain, 8, 8, 1);
```

for more information about thread numbers, check this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471442(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an IOS developer, but looking into this there is a function to see if your shader features are supported on the current device https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/1618849-mpssupportsmtldevice

You can also see what devices support which shader features here
https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf